# Content menu compartmentalisation

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm working on a Bolt driven website which has quite a few contenttypes. Some of which are related to one another. It would be nice to break down the content menu in the admin section to make it easier to see related content.

So for example the list currently is something like this:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
etc
```

I was thinking just a divider line similar to what appears in the settings menu would be enough to help the admin user's eye.

```
one
two
three
four
----------------
five
six
----------------
etc
```

Is there a way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is not possible.

You can however add fontawesome icons to your contenttypes for extra visual accessibility in the menu

```
icon_many: "fa:trophy"
icon_one: "fa:trophy"
```

Just replace trophy for any of the names in http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

And you can move some less used contenttypes to a submenu with the following option:

```
show_in_menu: false
```